# How to extract sub-categories of different levels from a root category using DBPedia?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I want to extract all sub-categories of "psychology" using DBPedia (in particular, I consider [this page](http://dbpedia.org/page/Category:Branches_of_psychology) as a starting point).

In [SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/) I wrote this query but it returns an empty set:

```
PREFIX  dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX  dbp:  <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT  ?branch ?discipline 
WHERE 
{
   ?branch a yago:BranchesOfPsychology
   OPTIONAL  { ?branch  dbo:academicDiscipline ?discipline }
}
ORDER BY  ?branch
```

This query extracts all direct sub-categories.

Assuming that `Branches of psychology` is a root, I want to extract sub-categories **from all levels**, **not only direct children of the root**. How can I do this for the example of psychology?

Comment: Please note that yago:BranchesOfPsychology isn't a DBpedia category, but a yago term.  It'd probably be more appropriate to look for something like dbc:Psychology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(this answer is to the originally posted question)

There are three issues with this query. One is the syntax for the object of `rdfs:label` and second one is the direction of `dct:subject`. When these two are corrected, your query will look like this:

```
select distinct ?subject
where {
?concept rdfs:label "Branches of psychology"@en .
?concept ^dct:subject ?subject .
} 
LIMIT 100
```

The third would be the performance of the query. In your case, you'll get the results if you increase execution timeout. [Here they are](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20distinct%20%3Fsubject%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fconcept%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%22Branches%20of%20psychology%22%40en%20.%0D%0A%3Fconcept%20%5Edct%3Asubject%20%3Fsubject%20.%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=300000&debug=on).

In addition,  I'd recommend avoiding triple patterns with strings. They are error prone.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I corrected my query but your proposal is better. But how to extract all sub-categories of sub-categories? I mean not only direct ones categories of "Branches of psychology".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, as I see it more as a "branch" than as a "root". With that reasoning, you can get more branches, replacing `^dct:subject/` with `^dct:subject/dct:subject`, and then, id there is an hierarchy, you can get it by adding `+` after each property from the property path. Again, that's based on assumption of what you are trying to get.